# Status of the extended form of the Lichtenbaum conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, l-functions

The extended Lichtenbaum conjecture concerns the relationship of special values of $L$-functions of number fields $K$, to the algebraic $K$-theory and etale cohomology of the ring of integers $O_K$.

For example, when $K$ is totally real and $n$ is even, it is known that (cf. Section 4.7.4 of [Kahn](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-540-27855-9_9)):

$$\zeta_{K}(1-n) = \pm 2^{r_1}  \frac{|K_{2n−2}(O_K)|}{|K_{2n−1}(O_K)|} = \pm \frac{|H^{2}(O_K;Z(n))|}{|H^1(O_K;Z(n))|}.$$

I am interested in the case $n$ odd. In that case, the conjectured value involves additionally a determinant of values of the Beilinson regulator. In particular, formula (4.34) of the aforementioned reference says that the conjectured value "should" be 
$$\lim_{s \to 1−n} (s+n)^{-g_n} \zeta_K(s) = \pm \frac{|H^{2}(O_K;Z(n))|}{|H^{1}(O_K;Z(n))_{tors}|} R'_n(K).$$

For certain number fields $K$, this is known to be true *up to a power of 2*, e.g. Theorem 4.1 of [Kolster](http://users.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns015/Kolster/Kolster_Final.pdf). However, this and other references go back a number of years, and it seems not impossible to me that nowadays more is known:

> For which number fields $K$ is the above formula for $\lim_{s \to 1−n} (s+n)^{-g_n} \zeta_K(s)$ known to be correct, without discarding powers of 2?

I am particularly interested in the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks very much for the question!

Looking it up a bit I found the PhD thesis "[The Lichtenbaum Conjecture at the Prime 2](https://macsphere.mcmaster.ca/handle/11375/14321)
" by Ion Rada (a student of Kolster) which proves that for every abelian number field $K$ and every odd integer $n \geq 3$ one has
$$ \zeta_K^{\ast}(1 - n) = \varepsilon_n(K) \cdot 2^{\mu_2(K^{+})} \cdot \frac{h_n(K)}{w_n(K)} \cdot R_n^{B}(K) $$
where:

- $\varepsilon_n(K) \in \{ \pm 1\}$ is determined by the $\Gamma$-factors in the functional equation;
- $h_n(K) := \prod_p \lvert H^2_{\text{et}}(\mathcal{O}_K^{S_p(K)},\mathbb{Z}_p(n)) \rvert$, where (as far as I understand) $S_p(K)$ is the set of places of $K$ consisting of the places lying above $p$ and the Archimedean places corresponding to real embeddings;
- $w_n(K) := \prod_p \, \lvert H^0(K,\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p(n))\rvert $;
- $R_n^B(K)$ denotes Beilinson's regulator;
- $K^{+}$ is the maximal real subfield of $K$;
- for every number field $F$ and every prime $p$ we set $\mu_p(F)$ to be the $\mu$-invariant of the module $U_p(F)/C_p(F)$, where $U_p(F)$ denotes the projective limits of the groups $\mathcal{O}_{F_{p^r}}^{\times}$, where $F_{p^r}$ denotes the $r$-th field in the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-tower of $F$, and $C_p(F)$ denotes the group of circular units.

I believe that the main ingredient is the proof of the Milnor conjecture by Voevodsky.